# Battleships OOP python

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, game, battleship

This is my first attempt at some basic OOP programming. A version of battleships played within the terminal. Any feedback would be great; especially in regards to readability and proper naming conventions.

I would really like to improve the strike function of the computer class to make it play more intelligently, any tips on that specifically?

ocean.py

```
class Ocean:

    """Creates 2D array the represents an ocean grid
    to veiw your ship positions

    Class contains all functions needed for placing
    ships on the ocean grid"""

    def __init__(self, width=10, height=10):
        self.ocean = [["~" for i in range(width)] for i in range(height)]

    def __getitem__(self, point):
        row, col = point
        return self.ocean[row][col]

    def __setitem__(self, point, value):
        row, col = point
        self.ocean[row][col] = value

    def view_ocean(self):
        for row in self.ocean:
            print(" ".join(row))

    # Two functions check a coordinate input is on the grid

    def valid_col(self, row):
        try:
            self.ocean[row]
            return True
        except IndexError:
            return False

    def valid_row(self, col):
        try:
            self.ocean[0][col]
            return True
        except IndexError:
            return False

    # Two functions check for valid board space for ship placement

    def can_use_col(self, row, col, size):

        valid_coords = []

        for i in range(size):

            if self.valid_col(col) and self.valid_row(row):
                if self.ocean[row][col] == "~":
                    valid_coords.append((row, col))
                    col = col + 1
                else:
                    col = col + 1
            else:
                return False

        if size == len(valid_coords):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def can_use_row(self, row, col, size):

        valid_coords = []

        for i in range(size):

            if self.valid_row(row) and self.valid_col(col):
                if self.ocean[row][col] == "~":
                    valid_coords.append((row, col))
                    row = row + 1
                else:
                    row = row + 1
            else:
                return False

        if size == len(valid_coords):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    # Corresponding fucntions set ship counters on valid space

    def set_ship_col(self, row, col, size):
        for i in range(size):
            self.ocean[row][col] = "S"
            col = col + 1

    def set_ship_row(self, row, col, size):
        for i in range(size):
            self.ocean[row][col] = "S"
            row = row + 1
```

radar.py

```
class Radar:

    """Creates a grid to track the state of an opponent's ocean grid"""

    def __init__(self, width=10, height=10):
        self.radar = [["." for i in range(width)] for i in range(height)]

    def __getitem__(self, point):
        row, col = point
        return self.radar[row][col]

    def __setitem__(self, point, value):
        row, col = point
        self.radar[row][col] = value

    def view_radar(self):
        for row in self.radar:
            print(" ".join(row))
```

ship.py

```
class Ship:

    def __init__(self, ship_type, size):
        self.ship_type = ship_type
        self.size = size
        self.coords = []

    def plot_vertical(self, row, col):
        for i in range(self.size):
            self.coords.append((row, col))
            row = row + 1

    def plot_horizontal(self, row, col):
        for i in range(self.size):
            self.coords.append((row, col))
            col = col + 1

    def check_status(self):
        if self.coords == []:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

player.py

```
from ocean import Ocean
from radar import Radar
from ship import Ship
import os

class Player:

    ships = {"Aircraft Carrier": 5, "Crusier": 4, "Destroyer": 3, 
"Submarine": 2}

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.ocean = Ocean()
        self.radar = Radar()
        self.name = name
        self.fleet = []

   # Function uses player input to set up fleet positions on a player board.
   # For each ship, a ship object containing relevant coordinates is appended to self.fleet

    def set_fleet(self):
        input("Pick a coordinate between 0 and 9 for the columns and rows on your board")
        input("Boats are placed form right to left.")
        for ship, size in self.ships.items():

            flag = True
            while flag:
                self.view_console()
                try:
                    print("Place your %s" % (ship))
                    row = int(input("Pick a row -----> "))
                    col = int(input("Pick a column -----> "))
                    orientation = str(input("Vertical or Horizontal? (choose v or h) -----> "))

                    if orientation in ["v", "V"]:
                        if self.ocean.can_use_row(row, col, size):
                            self.ocean.set_ship_row(row, col, size)
                            boat = Ship(ship, size)
                            boat.plot_vertical(row, col)
                            self.fleet.append(boat)
                            flag = False
                        else:
                            input("Overlapping ships, try again")

                    elif orientation in ["h", "H"]:
                        if self.ocean.can_use_col(row, col, size):
                            self.ocean.set_ship_col(row, col, size)
                            boat = Ship(ship, size)
                            boat.plot_horizontal(row, col)
                            self.fleet.append(boat)
                            flag = False
                        else:
                            input("Overlapping ships, try agin")

                    else:
                        continue

                    self.view_console()
                    input()
                    os.system('clear')

                except ValueError:
                    print("Don't you remember your training?\nType a number..\n")

    # Function displays player ocean/radar in readable format

    def view_console(self):
        self.radar.view_radar()
        print("|                 |")
        self.ocean.view_ocean()

    # Function checks status of ship objects within player fleet

    def register_hit(self, row, col):
        for boat in self.fleet:
            if (row, col) in boat.coords:
                boat.coords.remove((row, col))
                if boat.check_status():
                    self.fleet.remove(boat)
                    print("%s's %s has been sunk!" % (self.name, boat.ship_type))

    # Player interface for initiating in-game strikes,
    # updates the state of the boards of both players

    def strike(self, target):
        self.view_console()
        try:
            print("\n%s Pick your target..." % (self.name))
            row = int(input("Pick a row -----> "))
            col = int(input("Pick a column -----> "))

            if self.ocean.valid_row(row) and self.ocean.valid_col(col):
                if target.ocean.ocean[row][col] == "S":
                    print("DIRECT HIT!!!")
                    target.ocean.ocean[row][col] = "X"
                    target.register_hit(row, col)
                    self.radar.radar[row][col] = "X"

                else:
                    if self.radar.radar[row][col] == "O":
                        print("Area already hit....Check your radar!")
                        self.strike(target)
                    else:
                        print("Negative...")
                        self.radar.radar[row][col] = "O"

            else:
                print("Coordinates out of range...")
                self.strike(target)

        except ValueError:
            print("You need to provide a number....\n")
            self.strike(target)
        input()
        os.system('clear')
```

computer.py

```
from player import Player
from ship import Ship
import random


class Computer(Player):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.name = "Computer"

    # Automated version of set_fleet function from Player

    def set_compu_fleet(self):
        positions = ["v", "h"]

        for ship, size in self.ships.items():

            flag = True
            while flag:
                row = random.randint(0, 9)
                col = random.randint(0, 9)
                orientation = random.choice(positions)

                if orientation == "v":
                    if self.ocean.can_use_row(row, col, size):
                        self.ocean.set_ship_row(row, col, size)
                        boat = Ship(ship, size)
                        boat.plot_vertical(row, col)
                        self.fleet.append(boat)
                        flag = False

                    else:
                        row = row + 2

                elif orientation == "h":
                    if self.ocean.can_use_col(row, col, size):
                        self.ocean.set_ship_col(row, col, size)
                        boat = Ship(ship, size)
                        boat.plot_horizontal(row, col)
                        self.fleet.append(boat)
                        flag = False

                    else:
                        col = col + 2

                else:
                    continue

    # Automated strike function

    def compu_strike(self, target):
        row = random.randint(0, 9)
        col = random.randint(0, 9)

        if self.radar.radar[row][col] == ".":
            input("...Target acquired....%s, %s" % (row, col))

            if target.ocean.ocean[row][col] == "S":
                print("DIRECT HIT!")
                target.ocean.ocean[row][col] = "X"
                target.register_hit(row, col)
                self.radar.radar[row][col] = "X"

            else:
                print("Missed....recalibrating")
                self.radar.radar[row][col] = "O"

        else:
            self.compu_strike(target)
```

battlshipspvp.py

```
from player import Player
import os

# Player versus player mode


class BattleshipsPVP:
    """creates a game of battlehsips"""

    def __init__(self):
        start = input("Begin? (y or n) -----> ")
        if start in ["y", "Y"]:
            self.playPVP()
        else:
            print("Aborted...")

    def playPVP(self):
        p1name = input("Player 1, state your name! -----> ")
        p1 = Player(p1name)
        p1.set_fleet()
        p1.view_console()
        self.clear_screen()

        p2name = input("\n\nPlayer 2, state your name! -----> ") 
        p2 = Player(p2name)
        p2.set_fleet()
        p2.view_console()
        self.clear_screen()

        flag = True
        while flag is True:
            p1.strike(p2)
            if self.fleet_sunk(p2) is True:
                self.victory_message(p1, p2)
                flag = False
            else:
                self.clear_screen()

                p2.strike(p1)
                if self.fleet_sunk(p1) is True:
                    self.victory_message(p2, p1)
                    flag = False
                else:
                    self.clear_screen()
        print("\nThanks for playing!")

    # Function checks remaining ship counters on a player's board

    def fleet_sunk(self, player):
        ship_counters = 0
        """Traverses grid looking for 's' counters"""
        for row in range(len(player.ocean.ocean)):
            for col in range(len(player.ocean.ocean)):
                if player.ocean.ocean[row][col] == "S":
                    ship_counters += 1
        if ship_counters == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def clear_screen(self):
        input("\nNext Turn?")
        os.system('clear')

    def victory_message(self, winner, loser):
        print("\n\n\n*****************************************")
        print("%s's fleet has been destroyed, %s wins!" % (loser.name, winner.name))
        print("*****************************************")
```

battleshipscomp.py

```
from battleshipspvp import BattleshipsPVP
from computer import Computer
from player import Player


class BattleshipsCOMP(BattleshipsPVP):

    def __init__(self):
        start = input("Begin? (y or n) -----> ")
        if start in ["y", "Y"]:
        self.playCOMP()
        else:
            print("Aborted...")

    def playCOMP(self):
        pname = input("Player 1, state your name! -----> ")
        p = Player(pname)
        p.set_fleet()
        p.view_console()
        self.clear_screen()

        c = Computer()
        print("Computer setting its fleet...")
        c.set_compu_fleet()
        self.clear_screen()

        flag = True
        while flag is True:
            p.strike(c)
            if self.fleet_sunk(c) is True:
                self.victory_message(p, c)
                flag = False
            else:
                self.clear_screen()

                c.compu_strike(p)
                if self.fleet_sunk(p) is True:
                    self.victory_message(c, p)
                    flag = False
                else:
                    self.clear_screen()
        print("\nThanks for playing!")
```

playbattleships.py

```
from battleshipspvp import BattleshipsPVP
from battleshipscomputer import BattleshipsCOMP

# Script initiates game of battleships


def playbattleships():
    print("\n\n***********************")
    print("Welcome to Battleships!")
    print("***********************\n")

    print("\n 1) Player vs Player")
    print("\n 2) Player vs Computer")

    flag = True

    while flag:
        try:
            mode = int(input("\n\nPick a number to select a game mode ----> "))
            if mode == 1:
                flag = False
                BattleshipsPVP()
            elif mode == 2:
                flag = False
                BattleshipsCOMP()
            else:
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print("You can only pick either option 1 or 2")


playbattleships()
```

A view of the game board in play. The radar is the upper grid, the ocean is the lower grid.

```
. . . . . . . . . .
X . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . O . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
|                 |
S ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
S ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
S ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
S ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
S ~ ~ ~ ~ S S S S ~
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ S S X ~ ~
~ ~ S ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
~ ~ S ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
```

Comment: If you want to improve your `strike` function, I'd recommend [this nice article](http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/december32011/)

Answer (score 5):

### Use your own Interfaces

You've created both your `Ocean` class and `Radar` class to accept a `point` key in the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods.  Ie)

```
def __getitem__(self, point):
    row, col = point
    return self.ocean[row][col]

def __setitem__(self, point, value):
    row, col = point
    self.ocean[row][col] = value
```

But in your `Player` class, you avoid using those interfaces, and instead directly reach into the `Ocean` and `Radar` classes and manipulate the internals directly:

```
        if self.ocean.valid_row(row) and self.ocean.valid_col(col):
            if target.ocean.ocean[row][col] == "S":
                print("DIRECT HIT!!!")
                target.ocean.ocean[row][col] = "X"
                target.register_hit(row, col)
                self.radar.radar[row][col] = "X"
```

You should be using the interfaces you created:

```
        if self.ocean.valid_row(row) and self.ocean.valid_col(col):
            if target.ocean[row, col] == "S":
                print("DIRECT HIT!!!")
                target.ocean[row, col] = "X"
                target.register_hit(row, col)
                self.radar[row, col] = "X"
```

### Mark internals private

There is no "private" in Python, but by convention, if a member starts with a leading underscore, it should only be accessed by self.  So using `self._ocean` is ok, but using `self._ocean._ocean` would not be, as the second `._ocean` is reaching into another objects privates.

Ie:

```
class Ocean:
    def __init__(self, width=10, height=10):
        self._ocean = [["~" for i in range(width)] for i in range(height)]
```

So when you create `Player`, and you type `self.ocean._ocean`, you can think to yourself, "*wait ... I shouldn't be using that `._ocean` member of that `self.ocean` object; I should be calling a public method on `self.ocean` instead.*"

### Don't use Recursion for an Input Loop

Title says it all:

```
def strike(self, target):
    try:
        ...
                    print("Area already hit....Check your radar!")
                    self.strike(target)
        ...
    except ValueError:
        print("You need to provide a number....\n")
        self.strike(target)
    ...
```

If you repeatedly enter an already hit location, your stack will eventually overflow.  If you repeatedly enter an invalid row/col value, and get a `ValueError` exception, you'll get stack overflow while handling a `ValueError`, while handling a `ValueError`, while handling a `ValueError`, while handling a `ValueError`, while handling a `ValueError`, while ... a few thousand levels deep!

You did things better in `set_fleet()` with a `while flag:` loop.

### os.system('clear')

Don't use this.  Don't even use:

```
os.system('cls' if sys.platform == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

That is forking a new process, loading a shell processor, interpreting a command, which may launch yet-another-process, which clears the screen.  A little heavy weight.  And it is risky, if an executable, like `cls.bat` or `clear` is on the path; you could end up executing arbitrary instructions.

Use:

```
import colorama

def clear_screen():
    print(colorama.ansi.clear_screen())

colorama.init()

clear_screen()
```

Look at colorama for other interesting things you can do.  Like making your ocean blue, your ships green, and your hits red.

### Fixed Formatting

```
    print("|                 |")
```

What happens if your ocean is 8x8?  Or 12x12?  Will your vertical bars still properly line up?

```
    print("|" + " " * (2 * cols - 3) + "|")
```

would work better ... assuming `cols` is defined or replaced with something suitable.

Ditto with:

```
input("Pick a coordinate between 0 and 9 for the columns and rows on your board")
```

(Which as mentioned by Reinderien, should be a `print` statement.)  What if you changed your board size?

### Player-vs-Player  or  Player-vs-Computer

You've duplicated too much code.  Player -vs- Player, Player -vs- Computer, and Computer -vs- Computer can all be handled by 1 "game" function.

```
def play_game(side1, side2):

    side1.set_fleet()
    side2.set_fleet()

    while True:
        side1.strike(side2)
        if self.fleet_sunk(side2):
            self.victory_message(side1, side2)
            break
        else:
            side1, side2 = side2, side1
```

You games would be launched like:

```
p1 = Player(p1name)
p2 = Player(p2name)
play_game(p1, p2)
```

or

```
p1 = Player(p1name)
p2 = Computer()
play_game(p1, p2)
```

For this to work, `Computer` would need a `set_fleet()` method, instead of a `set_compu_fleet()` method, as well as a `strike()` method instead of a `compu_strike()` method.

### f-strings

If using Python 3.6+, instead of:

```
    print("%s's %s has been sunk!" % (self.name, boat.ship_type))
```

use:

```
    print(f"{self.name}'s {boat.ship_type} has been sunk!")
```

### Antipatterns

Avoid `is True`.  For example, `while flag is True:`.  Use `while flag:`

Avoid `if condition: return True else: return False`.  Use, `return condition`.  For example:

```
    if ship_counters == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

should be:

```
    return ship_counters == 0
```

Avoid `for idx in range(len(item)): blah(item[idx])`.  Use `for val in item: blah(val)`.

For example:

```
ship_counters = 0
for row in range(len(player.ocean.ocean)):
    for col in range(len(player.ocean.ocean)):
        if player.ocean.ocean[row][col] == "S":
            ship_counters += 1
```

Would be better written as:

```
ship_counters = 0
for ocean_row in player.ocean.ocean:
    for cell in ocean_row:
        if cell == "S":
            ship_counters += 1
return ship_counters == 0
```

Or better:

```
ship_counters = sum(1 for row in player.ocean.ocean for cell in row if cell == "S")
return ship_counters == 0
```

Or even better:

```
return all(cell != 'S' for row in player.ocean.ocean for cell in row)
```

### Docstrings

I disagree with @Reinderien's point:

> This comment:
>   `# Function uses player input to set up fleet positions on a player board.`.
>   `# For each ship, a ship object containing relevant coordinates is appended to self.fleet`.
>   belongs on the first line inside the function, in triple quotes.

The above is a comment, not a docstring.

- A `# comment` is used to document code for the **reader** of the code.
- A `"""docstring"""` is used to provide usage documentation for a **caller** who may not have access to the source code.

  class Player:

  ```
  # Function uses player input to set up fleet positions on a player board.
  # For each ship, a ship object containing relevant coordinates is appended to self.fleet

  def set_fleet(self):
      """
      Ask the user to assign locations to their fleet's ships.

      Parameters: None
      Returns: Nothing
      """
  ```

Now, type `help(Player.set_fleet)`.  You will see the `doc-string` help, which is designed to help the caller.  From this description, the caller would know that they don't need to write `fleet = player.set_fleet()`, since nothing is returned.

In contrast, someone reading the code (maybe to debug it, modify it, enhance it) will want to know what the code does.  Appending a ship object to `self.fleet` is useful internal details the caller may not need to know.

See also [sphinx-doc.org](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) for an automated docstring processing utility which can generate HTML doc pages, pdf help documents, etc., all by reading the docstrings directly from the code.

Answer (score 2):

### Type hints

PEP484 type hints will help document and test your code. For example,

```
def can_use_col(self, row, col, size):
```

can be (I guess)

```
def can_use_col(self, row: int, col: int, size: int) -> bool:
```

### In-place addition

```
col = col + 1
```

can be

```
col += 1
```

### Logic-by-exception

This:

```
    try:
        self.ocean[row]
        return True
    except IndexError:
        return False
```

can simply be

```
return row in self.ocean
```

### can_use_col

This method shouldn't need to form a list. Let's see if we can improve it.

First: replace `i` with `_` since you don't use it. Also, instead of `valid_coords` as a list, you can maintain it as a count starting at 0. Increment it instead of appending to a list.

Also, don't repeat yourself - only do `col += 1` once, in the scope above where you have it now.

Use a boolean directly by writing `return size == len(valid_coords)` instead of using an `if` statement. The same goes for this code:

```
    if self.coords == []:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

### Iteration

```
    for i in range(size):
        self.ocean[row][col] = "S"
        row = row + 1
```

Again, you don't use `i`, but you're also maintaining an index in `row`. Instead:

```
    for i in range(size):
        self.ocean[row + i][col] = "S"
```

This also solves the issue that you're changing an argument to your function, which you generally shouldn't.

### Docstrings

This comment:

```
# Function uses player input to set up fleet positions on a player board.
# For each ship, a ship object containing relevant coordinates is appended to self.fleet
```

belongs on the first line inside the function, in triple quotes.

### Typo

```
"Boats are placed form right to left."
```

form = from.

### Input prompts

```
   input("Boats are placed form right to left.")
```

I'm not sure what this is asking the user to input, and they won't be either. Did you mean to write `print` here?

### Character comparison

```
if orientation in ["v", "V"]:
```

If you actually needed to compare against multiple things, you should use a set instead of a list:

```
if orientation in {"v", "V"}:
```

However, your case is easier than that:

```
if orientation.lower() == 'v':
```

Comment: Thanks man I really appreciate it.

Comment: `return row in self.ocean` will not work if the `ocean` is a list of lists. This can work if the ocean is a dict

Answer (score 2):

## files

Python is not Java. Multiple classes can be in the same module (file)

## grid

There is a lot of repetition between `Ocean` and `Radar`. You can use a lot of overlapping code

## enum

instead of `"."` or `"~"` to denote what is in the grid, you could use Enums, and let the board representation method (`view_radar` for example) take care of how to represent this.

## collection types

You only seem to use `list`s. Even when you only use the collection soo see whether something is in it, and order is not important. `set`s or `dict`s can be more suited on some moments. Get to know when to use which type of collection

## orientation

You have a lot of methods that are the same, but one is for horizonatal, the other for vertical. This can be tackled by adding a parameter orientation (Which should be an Enum) to the method.

```
def plot_vertical(self, row, col):
    for i in range(self.size):
        self.coords.append((row, col))
        row = row + 1


def plot_horizontal(self, row, col):
    for i in range(self.size):
        self.coords.append((row, col))
        col = col + 1
```

can then be replaced by:

```
import enum

class Orientation(enum.Enum):
    Horizontal = (1, 0)
    Vertical = (0, 1)


def plot(self, row, col, orientation):
    d_col, d_row = orientation.value
    self.coords.extend(
        (row + i * d_row, col + i * d_col) for i in range(self.size)
    )
```

Even better would be to incorporate this in the ship's `__init__`, so the 2 steps in the placing of the fleet:

```
boat = Ship(ship, size)
boat.plot_vertical(row, col)
```

can become :

```
class Ship:

    def __init__(self, ship_type, size, position, orientation):
        self.ship_type = ship_type
        self.size = size
        row, col = position
        d_col, d_row = orientation.value
        self.coords = [(row + i * d_row, col + i * d_col) for i in range(self.size)]
```

and be called:

```
boat = Ship(ship, size, (row, col), orientation)
```